# Git command alias configuration in ~/.gitconfig

Tags: git, github

I want to create **alias** for my **Git** commands, so, I edited my *~/.gitconfig* file to be like this:

```
email = my.name@gmail.com
name = My Name
git config --global alias.st status
git config --global alias.co checkout
git config --global alias.ci commit
```

Then, in my project, when I try to run git command, I always got error message :

```
fatal: bad config file line 4 in /Users/myname/.gitconfig
```

Where am I wrong??

Answer (score 2):

You are putting actual git commands in your .gitconfig. Those commands should either be run to modify your .gitconfig from a command line, or if you want to modify your .gitconfig directly it would look something like this:

```
[alias]
  st = status
  co = checkout
  ci = commit
```

If there is already an [alias] section in your gitconfig, put your aliases under the existing section.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but when I run "git st" in my project, it does not consider it as a git command. It seems your suggestion does not set the alias globally or something wrong ???

Comment: What platform are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Rename your .gitconfig file to set it aside, then run the following commands from the command line:

```
git config user.name "Your Name"
git config user.email "your email"
git config alias.st status
git config alias.co checkout
git config alias.ci commit
```

The result should be a `.gitconfig` file that looks something like:

```
[user]
        name = Your Name
        email = your email
[alias]
        st=status
        co=checkout
        ci=commit
```